# Angular JS code using mongo query not publishing results of query to UI

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing functionality in my MEAN stack app which will allow me to get a list of all businesses in the database that lie within a certain distance of a chosen location.  Here's my code:

```
if (fullAddress) {

        queryAdvns = Listing.aggregate().near(
            {
                near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lng, lat]},
                distanceField: 'distance',
                maxDistance: within,
                query: query._conditions,
                spherical: true,
                distanceMultiplier: 0.00062137,
                num: 1000,
                limit: 1000
            });

        queryCount = Listing.aggregate().near(
            {
                near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lng, lat]},
                distanceField: 'distance',
                maxDistance: within,
                query: query._conditions,
                spherical: true,
                distanceMultiplier: 0.00062137,
                num: 1000,
                limit: 1000
            });
    }

    if (fullAddress) {

        logger.info("Searching by Distance");
        queryCount
            .limit(1000)
            .exec(function (err, list) {

                logger.info("Counting Advance Search Result");
                if (!err) {

                    var newLimit = limit + skip;

                    queryAdvns
                        .sort(sort)
                        .limit(newLimit)
                        .skip(skip)
                        .exec(function (err, result) {
                            res.json({
                                searchResult: result,
                                count: list.length
                            });
                        });

                } else {
                    return next(err);
                }

            });


    }
```

When I run the query in my app, I get the following error message: "error: MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument" and my app doesn't produce any results on the UI.

I'm running mongo version 4.0.2 on my local environment, where I get this error and behavior.  When I run the exact same code on my development server which uses Mongo version 3.2.13, the same code runs effectively and successfully publishes the query results in the UI.  From what I understand, I need to include the cursor option or explain argument with the aggregate command in the query because Mongo version 3.6 (and beyond) have disallowed use of aggregate command without the cursor option or explain argument.

I'm not very good with the aggregate command and therefore cannot figure out how to modify this code to include the cursor option or explain argument.  Appreciate some help.

Comment: From what I can glean from the logs, it appears that my code is also getting stuck when executing
           queryCount.limit(1000).exec(function (err, list)
because it doesn't print any messages after this line.  Presuming this is a mongoose issue?

Comment: Also learnt that Mongoose versions earlier than 5.0 incorrectly throw the error about requiring cursor option or explain argument with aggregate command.  Apparently upgrading to Mongoose 5.0 should fix it.  I've never updated Mongoose using npm.  Is it as simple as "npm update Mongoose@5.0.0"?  Anything else (like updating schemas or modules) that I need to worry about when updating Mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, discovered that this issue arises because of a mismatch between the versions of MongoDB and Mongoose.  The problem described above occurred because I was using MongoDB version 4.0.2 and Mongoose 4.4.5.  MongoDB version 3.6 onward removed the ability to use the aggregate command without the cursor option unless the command includes the explain argument.  Downgrading to MongoDB version 3.2 resolved the issue for me.  Turns out that there's also some sort of a bug in Mongoose versions before 5.0 that incorrectly throw this error even though the aggregate command is correctly written using MongoDB versions 3.6 and beyond (ie, using aggregate command with cursor option or explain argument).  So if you're using MongoDB 3.6+, you should use Mongoose 5.0+.

Summary - avoid MongoDB/Mongoose version mismatches.  For MongoDB versions before 3.6, use Mongoose 4.4.5.  For MongoDB versions post 3.6, use Mongoose 5.0 and above.